# How Fixing Warning Mapping New ns in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i was updated my Android Studio and i face this type of issue in **flutter**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw2IM.png)

```
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
```

*i was researched to fix that issue, using gradle version updated. but it was fix that flutter project only. i was tired, when i was run an new flutter project coming that same issue.*

**please,** let me know,

how to fix this problem **permanently.**your help is so appreciated

*Thank you in Advance.*

Answer (score 0):

Warning:Mapping new ns to old ns

1. Clean your project: Run `flutter clean`
2. Update gradle-wrapper.properties: Go to *<project>/android/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties* , then set the value of `distributionUrl` to whatever latest gradle distribution is available; currently: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip
3. Update build.gradle: Update *<project>/android/build.gradle* with the newest version of Gradle and Kotlin available.
   `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'` (latest [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle?repo=google)) and `ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'` (latest [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions))
4. Final Step: Run `flutter packages get`, then run your flutter app. The first run may take more time as the IDE downloads new files.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).